# Is Significance level of Zero percent possible?

Tags: statistical-significance, panel-data

I have ran Fixed Effects Panel regression. I have received significance level of all coefficients from X1 to X4 at zero percent level. I presented the results. So, it is possible that the coefficients are significant at zero percent level as well as the F stat value to be very high although R square is low. How can I defend such significance level or is there some problem in my data?

```
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = Y ~ X, data = pdata1, model = "within")

Unbalanced Panel: n=3197, T=1-120, N=194474

Residuals :
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.25000 -0.01360  0.00285  0.01360  0.12200 

Coefficients :
      Estimate  Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
X1 -5.1870e-02  1.2390e-03 -41.864 < 2.2e-16 ***
X2 -6.7562e+04  7.9405e+02 -85.085 < 2.2e-16 ***
X3  7.3749e-02  1.8016e-03  40.934 < 2.2e-16 ***
X4 -2.6536e-03  5.5102e-05 -48.159 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    78.636
Residual Sum of Squares: 73.744
R-Squared:      0.062216
Adj. R-Squared: 0.061192
F-statistic: 3172.43 on 4 and 191273 DF, p-value: < 2.22e-16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A significance level equal to zero in that output means $< 0.0001$. In your specific case, the p-value is smaller than the machine's precision (2.2e-16). You obtain such small p-values because you are dealing with a huge amount of observations ($N=194474$).

Theoretically speaking, you can't have a zero significance level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have never seen significance level of 0 in any research paper. Is it possible to change the significance level. I feel my professor won't trust my results.

Comment: Indeed, a p-value equal to zero will be hinky (and wrong). You should report a significance level smaller than 0.0001 (or another threshold, depending on your data: some results should be significant at 0.05 level, other should be significant at 0.000001 level).

Comment: You have mentioned threshold depending on data, how can I estimate that?

Comment: You can't. Maybe my last sentence was not clear. I meant that some results are meaningful if they are significant at 0.000001 level (e.g. physics, chemistry, astronomy), whereas other results can be considered meaningful if they are significant at 0.05 (e.g. psychology, sociology, economics). It depends on your field of study, but you can't estimate such a threshold.